# Computing probability of equally random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

For the case of 2 possibilities (A and B), I can (computational) create a random number r = [0,1] and assign the probability of A to be r, and probability of B to be (1-r) so that they follow the same distribution. But what about the case of 3 possibilities (A,B and C)?

Comment: Choose three values at random from $[0,1]$ and scale by their sum.

Comment: Thanks lulu ;) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach is to choose three values uniformly at random from $[0,1]$ and then rescale them by their sum.  This (obviously) extends to $n$ variables.

Alternatively, you can choose three values successively from $[0,1]$ in such a way that the sum is forced to be $1$ though the natural methods of doing this will not produce equi-distributed choices.  You can counter this effect by assigning your three values to $A,B,C$ uniformly randomly at the end.  That will give you three equi-distributed variables.

Answer (score 0):

If your Sample Space consists only of events: A, B and C
 (they may be Mutually exclusive or Exhaustive), then:
$$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$$

So, you may want to assign random probabilities to any **2** of **A, B** and **C**, taking care that the **2** random numbers generated sum  to $\leq$ $1$

This will require you to restrict your set of probabilities $[0,1]$.

For e.g:
Assume that you allot a probability of **0.4** to say, **A**.
Now, for **B**(or C), you will have to restrict $[0,1]$ to $[0,0.6]$

After getting P(A) and P(B), use $$P(C)=1-P(A)-P(B)$$ to get P(C)

Comment: No.. doesn't work.. they will not have the same distribution. Read the answer from lulu (he's right)

Comment: it is quite similar, we are assigning 2 randomly chosen probabilities, and getting 3rd one by Addition Theorem

Comment: In your case, the mean of A and B will be 0.5. They must be 1/3

Comment: can't it be P(A)=0.2, P(B)=0.3 and P(C)=0.5 ?  mean of A and B is not 0.5

Comment: Are you assuming A,B and C to be equi-probable? to have it 1/3

Comment: With this construction, the mean of $A$ is clearly $.5$ (uniform on $[0,1]$).  The mean of $B$ however is not $.5$.  To compute it, note that for a given choice, $x$, for $A$, the mean of $B$ is clearly $\frac {1-x}2$.  Thus the mean of $B$ is $\int_0^1 \frac {1-x}2 \,dx=.25$.  By Linearity, that is also the mean of $C$.  In any case, the means are not all equal, so the constructed variables can not be equi-distributed.